# How do I add a variable and a string together to get another variable

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dictionary called enemyPokemon which contains 4 enemyPokemon and I have more dictionaries that contain the moves that the enemies can do which are the Pokemon's names followed by 'Fight'.

I'm trying to choose a random move from the moves list depending on what enemyPokemon you are fighting, however, I don't know how to do that.

This is the code that I've written:

x is a variable that chooses one of the 4 enemy Pokemon.

```
enemyPokemon = {
    1: 'Slowpoke',
    2: 'Eevee',
    3: 'Piplup',
    4: 'Rattata',
}

SlowpokeFight = {
    1:'Water Pulse',
    2:'Zen Headbutt',
    3:'Tackle',
    4:'Rain Dance',
}
EeveeFight = {
    1:'Sand Attack',
    2:'Bite',
    3:'Double-Edge',
    4:'Last Resort',
}
PiplupFight = {
    1:'Water Sport',
    2:'Peck',
    3:'Bubble',
    4:'Drill Peck',
}
RattataFight = {
    1:'Tail Whip',
    2:'Quick Attack',
    3:'Hyper Fang',
    4:'Crunch',
}


randomMove = random.randint(1,4)
 whatEnemy = str(enemyPokemon[int(x)])+'Fight')
 print (str(whatEnemy[int(randomMove)]))
 print (randomMove)
 print (whatEnemy[int(x)])
```

Comment: what is the error here ?
update : 2nd line of code `whatEnemy = str(enemyPokemon[int(x)])+'Fight'`

Comment: It might be helpful if you could edit your post to include the dictionaries that you're using, so we can see how you've set things up and what you might need to change to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to using a nested dictionary instead, this allows you to map your moves to your pokemon.

You can do it this way by putting them into two dictionaries.

```
import random

enemyPokemon = {
    1: 'Slowpoke',
    2: 'Eevee',
    3: 'Piplup',
    4: 'Rattata',
}

pokemonMoves = {
    'Slowpoke' : {
        1:'Water Pulse',
        2:'Zen Headbutt',
        3:'Tackle',
        4:'Rain Dance'
    },
    'Eevee' : {
        1:'Sand Attack',
        2:'Bite',
        3:'Double-Edge',
        4:'Last Resort'
    }
    # ...
}

randomMove = random.randint(1, 4)
enemy = enemyPokemon[randomMove]
move = pokemonMoves[enemy][randomMove]

print(enemy)
print(move)
```

You may even be inclined to have just one dictionary of the Pokemon names as the keys and a dictionary of their moves as the values.

```
import random

pokemon = {
    'Slowpoke' : {
        1:'Water Pulse',
        2:'Zen Headbutt',
        3:'Tackle',
        4:'Rain Dance'
    },
    'Eevee' : {
        1:'Sand Attack',
        2:'Bite',
        3:'Double-Edge',
        4:'Last Resort'
    }
    # ...
}

# creates a list of all the keys (pokemon names from dict)
allPokemon = list(pokemon) 

randomMove = random.randint(1, 4)
enemy = random.choice(allPokemon)
move = pokemon[enemy][randomMove]

print(enemy)
print(move)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call variable from string this is what you need:

```
whatEnemy = globals()[(str(enemyPokemon[int(x)])+'Fight')]
```